# Why my Firefox and IE cannot load 3D canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

[This page](https://joshcarllewis.com/static/articles/html5-3d-canvas-tutorial/demo.html) used html5 3D canvas. In November last year, I used Firefox to access the page, it works fine. But now I find that I can't load the page using IE or Firefox(they show a black window, with no earth), it only works on Chrome. It's so weird. The tutorial and the code of the js can be found at: joshcarllewis.com/articles/html5-3d-canvas-tutorial .(sorry I can't insert more than two links.)

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O1444.png) is what you should see after opening the page.

Comment: I guess you have latest versions of both browsers. http://caniuse.com check if that is available for your version of browsers.

Comment: It works fine in Firefox 44 here, also in IE11. (on Windows 8.1)

Comment: Works fine in IE11/Win7 here.

Comment: Feedback: After a few seconds delay, your spinning earth does correctly appear in my IE11.63.10586 and also correctly on my FF44.0 running on Win10.

Comment: Try clearing your respective cache's.  It appears to be working for others